# Simple Javascript file not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to make a small game using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The HTML and CSS and most of the Javascript code appear to be working fine. However, when launch the program in FireFox and try to click a square div whose background RGB value matches that of a RGB value stored in a variable I get the wrong answer. It is suppose to alert the user with "Correct" but instead all the alerts are outputting "Wrong".

Here is the HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE>  
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame3.css">
</head>
    <body>

        <h1>
        RGB Color Game
        <span id = "colorDisplay">
        RGB
        </span>
        </h1>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame3.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS file

```
    body{
    background-color: #232323;
    }

.square{
width:30%;
background:purple;
padding-bottom:30%;
float:left;
margin:1.66%;

 }

#container{

max-width:600px;
margin:20px auto;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript file

```
    var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
    ]

    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

     var pickedColor = colors[2];

    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

      colorDisplay.textContent =  pickedColor;

      for(var i = 0; i<squares.length;i++){

squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

var clickedColor = this.style.background;

    if(clickedColor === pickedColor){

        alert("Correct");

    }
    else{

        alert("Wrong");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What errors do you see on the console ?

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using background instead of backgroundColor. But I'm not sure

Comment: You should console.log `pickedColor` and `clickedColor`, they are not the same value. In Chrome at least, might be the same in Firefox, the value gets formatted with spaces after the comma separators when getting the value back from `style.background`

Comment: clickedColor = rgb(0, 255, 0)  and pickedColor = rgb(0,255,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colors `pickedColor` and `clickedColor` do not match even though they both "technically" work in `CSS`. `this.style.background;` is inserting a space between each color.  They need to look like this ...

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

your if condition doesnt match. there is space.

this is the alert code `alert (pickedColor + clickedColor);`
[image]